# How to cast a mobile web page on Android?

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-chrome, google-cast

I'm working on Chromecast's [Hello World app](https://github.com/googlecast/CastHelloText-chrome) for Chrome browsers, but I hit a roadblock when I tested it on my Android device. As far as I can tell, there is no way to cast the Chrome tab itself on Android. The only option is to cast the entire screen.

I've found an old [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Chromecast/comments/3do559/how_to_cast_a_tab_from_android_chrome_browser/) and an even older [Google Cast Help Forum thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chromecast/JK5s9bXpmxU). Neither source makes it seem like it's possible to cast a mobile web tab on Android.

This is really hard to believe because I don't see anything intrinsic about a web page being on a mobile device that would prevent it from being Cast-compatible. What am I missing?

The current state of casting on a mobile device seems to be:

1. Casting audio/video content from the mobile Chrome browser
2. Casting from native mobile applications
3. Casting the entire device's screen

The specific use case I'm looking to implement is a web-based game where players can be on a couch in front of a TV. They play the game by visiting a website in Chrome rather than downloading an app. If they were on laptops, it would work just fine because desktop Chrome is able to cast a specific tab where the TV shows some application like in the Hello World example. But this wouldn't be possible with Android.

Is anyone aware of a way to cast a mobile web page or any upcoming plans to do so?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27049265/how-can-i-cast-an-html-page-with-the-google-cast-chrome-extension?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using `Webview`. It will automatically consider mobile view only. Try this: make the `main.xml` file like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_gravity="center">
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center" /></LinearLayout>
```

Now make a class:

```
WebViewSampleActivity

    public class WebViewSampleActivity extends Activity {
     WebView wb;
    private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);      
        wb=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);        
        wb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wb.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        wb.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        wb.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        wb.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
        wb.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);           
        wb.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
        wb.loadUrl("http://www.yourUrl.com");        
    }
}
```

Comment: So the webview requires users to download an Android app that will load a web page? Does the web page run with the desktop Chrome capabilities of the Cast API? If it's just mobile Chrome in an Android app, I've done a lot of work to get the same broken behavior.

Comment: Yes it will allow user to download the app...it will be available in google play like other app.

Comment: No my concern is whether the webview runs in a desktop or mobile Chrome environment. The difference is that you can't cast from mobile, which is what this question is trying to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

Create a webview and inject a url. so easy way.